# how to update a particular item or task in a todo list app made using ionic framework

Tags: angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I'm making a todo list app using ionic framework with update feature.
Whenever we click on an item a new update modal popups and ask for update.I have made till this point but don't know how to make it functional(means how to actually update the item) .
I have searched all over the internet but didn't find anything helpful.
I'm sharing the code of index.html,app.js and contollers.js
Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Todo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- Needed for Cordova/PhoneGap (will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="todo" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <ion-side-menus>

    <!-- Center content -->
<ion-side-menu-content drag-content="true">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-royal">
    <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="toggleProjects()">
      <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
    </button>
    <h1 class="title">{{activeProject.title}}</h1>
    <!-- New Task button-->
    <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="newTask()">
      <i class="icon ion-compose"></i>
    </button>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content scroll="true">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="task in activeProject.tasks" >
        <div ng-click="updateTask()">
        {{task.title}}

        </div>


      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu-content>

    <!-- Left menu -->
  <ion-side-menu side="left" width="150">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
      <h1 class="title">Projects</h1>
      <button class="button button-icon ion-plus" ng-click="newProject()">
      </button>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content scroll="true">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="project in projects" ng-click="selectProject(project, $index)" ng-class="{active: activeProject == project}">
          {{project.title}}
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>

  //Create Task
    <script id="new-task.html" type="text/ng-template">

  <div class="modal">

    <!-- Modal header bar -->
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-secondary">
      <h1 class="title">Add New Task</h1>
      <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="closeNewTask()">Cancel</button>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <!-- Modal content area -->
    <ion-content>

      <form ng-submit="createTask(task)">
        <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="What do you want to do?" ng-model="task.title">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="padding">
          <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-dark">Create Task</button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </ion-content>

  </div>

</script>

<!-- Update task here -->
<script id="update-task.html" type="text/ng-template">

  <div class="modal">

    <!-- Modal header bar -->
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-secondary">
      <h1 class="title">Update Task</h1>
      <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="closeUpdateTask()">Cancel</button>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <!-- Modal content area -->
    <ion-content>

      <form ng-submit="UpdateTask(task)">
        <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Edit your stuff here?" ng-model="task.title">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="padding">
          <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-dark">Update Task</button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </ion-content>

  </div>

</script>

  </ion-side-menus>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])
/**
 * The Projects factory handles saving and loading projects
 * from local storage, and also lets us save and load the
 * last active project index.
 */
.factory('Projects', function() {
  return {
    all: function() {
      var projectString = window.localStorage['projects'];
      if(projectString) {
        return angular.fromJson(projectString);
      }
      return [];
    },
    save: function(projects) {
      window.localStorage['projects'] = angular.toJson(projects);
    },
    newProject: function(projectTitle) {
      // Add a new project
      return {
        title: projectTitle,
        tasks: []
      };
    },
    getLastActiveIndex: function() {
      return parseInt(window.localStorage['lastActiveProject']) || 0;
    },
    setLastActiveIndex: function(index) {
      window.localStorage['lastActiveProject'] = index;
    }
  }
})

.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $ionicModal, Projects, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

  // A utility function for creating a new project
  // with the given projectTitle
  var createProject = function(projectTitle) {
    var newProject = Projects.newProject(projectTitle);
    $scope.projects.push(newProject);
    Projects.save($scope.projects);
    $scope.selectProject(newProject, $scope.projects.length-1);
  }


  // Load or initialize projects
  $scope.projects = Projects.all();

  // Grab the last active, or the first project
  $scope.activeProject = $scope.projects[Projects.getLastActiveIndex()];

  // Called to create a new project
  $scope.newProject = function() {
    var projectTitle = prompt('Project name');
    if(projectTitle) {
      createProject(projectTitle);
    }
  };

  // Called to select the given project
  $scope.selectProject = function(project, index) {
    $scope.activeProject = project;
    Projects.setLastActiveIndex(index);
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(false);
  };

  // Create our modal
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('new-task.html', function(modal) {
    $scope.taskModal1 = modal;
  }, {
    scope: $scope
  });

  // Create our modal
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('update-task.html', function(modal) {
    $scope.taskModal2 = modal;
  }, {
    scope: $scope
  });

  $scope.createTask = function(task) {
    if(!$scope.activeProject || !task) {
      return;
    }
    $scope.activeProject.tasks.push({
      title: task.title
    });
    $scope.taskModal1.hide();

    // Inefficient, but save all the projects
    Projects.save($scope.projects);

    task.title = "";
  };

  $scope.UpdateTask = function(task) {

  };

  $scope.newTask = function() {
    $scope.taskModal1.show();
  };

   $scope.updateTask = function() {
    $scope.taskModal2.show();
  };

  $scope.closeNewTask = function() {
    $scope.taskModal1.hide();
  }
  $scope.closeUpdateTask = function() {
    $scope.taskModal2.hide();
  }

  $scope.toggleProjects = function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };


  // Try to create the first project, make sure to defer
  // this by using $timeout so everything is initialized
  // properly
  $timeout(function() {
    if($scope.projects.length == 0) {
      while(true) {
        var projectTitle = prompt('Your first project title:');
        if(projectTitle) {
          createProject(projectTitle);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  });

});
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])

.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
  // No need for testing data anymore
  $scope.tasks = [];

  // Create and load the Create task Modal
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('update-task.html', function(modal) {
      id: 1;
    $scope.taskModal1 = modal;
  }, {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  });

  // Create and load the Update Task Modal
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('update-task.html', function(modal) {
      id: 2;
    $scope.taskModal2 = modal;
  }, {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  });

  // Called when the form is submitted
  $scope.createTask = function(task) {
    $scope.tasks.push({
      title: task.title
    });
    $scope.taskModal1.hide();
    task.title = "";
  };

  // Called when the task is to be updated
  $scope.UpdateTask = function(task) {

  };

  // Open our new task modal
  $scope.newTask = function() {
    $scope.taskModal1.show();
  };

  // Open our update task modal
  $scope.updateTask = function() {
    $scope.taskModal2.show();
  };

  // Close the new task modal
  $scope.closeNewTask = function() {
    $scope.taskModal.hide();
  };
});
```

Can someone tell me how to update a task???

// Called when the task is to be updated

```
$scope.UpdateTask = function(task) {

     //.............

  };
```

Comment: Sharing a plunker for the same will allow us to make direct changes, rather than from scratch code.

Comment: Share a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) @Hemant.

Comment: I have never used plunker.Trying it for the first time but seems its getting very difficult for me.So if you can solve my problem without plunker that would be best. @TechMa9iac

Answer (score 0):

This are the steps you can follow :

1. When user selects a task, save the index into a temp scope variable, and copy that task into some other variable [currentTask].

   ```
   $scope.UpdateTask = function(index) {
       $scope.currentIndex = index;
       $scope.currentTask = angular.copy($scope.tasks[$index]);
   };
   ```
2. In the form that opens, all the model fields should be bound to currentTask.

   ```
   <form ng-submit="saveTask()">
       <div class="list">
           <label class="item item-input">
               <input type="text" placeholder="Edit your stuff here?" ng-model="currentTask.title">
           </label>
       </div>
       <div class="padding">
           <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-dark">Update Task</button>
       </div>
   </form>
   ```
3. update the values using the index.

   ```
   $scope.sveTask = function(index) {
       if ($scope.$scope.currentIndex === -1) {
           $scope.tasks.push(angular.copy($scope.tasks[$index]));
       } else {
           $scope.tasks[$scope.currentIndex] = angular.copy($scope.tasks[$index]);
       }


       $scope.currentIndex = -1;
       $scope.currentTask = {};
   };
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I will try to implement it @TechMa9iac